# XPath return value on sibling value multiple with conditions

Tags: html, xml, xpath

This is how the HTML is structured; I am attempting to obtain the value of `<div>` if the sibling `<p>` is equal to type1

```
<div class="zsg-lg">
  <div class="hdp-fact-ataglance">
     <div class="media-bd">
        <p>
           type1
        <div>
            value
<div class="zsg-lg">
  <div class="hdp-fact-ataglance">
     <div class="media-bd">
        <p>
           type2
        <div>
            value2
```

Here's my XPath that's currently not working, I'm pretty confused on how to structure it.

```
div[contains(@class, "zsg-lg")]/div[contains(@class, "hdp-fact-ataglance")]/div[contains(@class, "media-bd") and [p == "Type"]]/div/text()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
normalize-space(
  //div[contains(@class, "zsg-lg")]
  /div[contains(@class, "hdp-fact-ataglance")]
  /div[
      contains(@class, "media-bd")
    and
      normalize-space(p/text())="type1"
  ]
  /div
  /text()
)
```

Comment: this works too thanks; can you explain the utility of normalize-space?

Comment: It trims spaces (and a few other minor things), which helps if your HTML looks like `<p> newline and spaces here type1 newline and spaces here </p>` rather than `<p>type1</p>`.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the syntax was a little off, this worked:

```
div[contains(@class, "zsg-lg")]/div[contains(@class, "hdp-fact-ataglance")]/div[contains(@class, 'media-bd') and p = 'type1']/div/text()
```